# Virtuemart cart customisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, virtuemart

I am attempting to customise a virtuemart 2 cart. It is for an insurance website and i would like to be able to add a checkbox to the cart which allows the user to add certain extra products to their order. Has anyone seen this done before? or know how it can be done?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('input#liabiliy_field').live('change',function () {
         if(jQuery(this).is(':checked')){ //I like it using this way

         var tmp=window.open('/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart&task=add&virtuemart_product_id[]=3&virtuemart_category_id[]=1&quantity[]=1', 'window name', 'window settings');
         tmp.close();
         return false;

          } 
     });
});
```